# Need assistance regarding autolayout anchors

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout

I am learning auto layout anchors and trying to achieve this simple thing programmatically

[image]

And here my code

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    let view1 = UIView()
    view1.backgroundColor = .brown
    blueView.addSubview(view1)

    view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.topAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true
    view1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.bottomAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true
    view1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.leadingAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true
    view1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.trailingAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true
    view1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    view1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
}
```

And this is what I am getting

[image]

What is going wrong?

Comment: Please pot the image instead of a link.

Comment: What result are you expecting? Without setting up a test project, things look about right to me - you're setting the leading/trailing and top/bottom anchors to be offset of the blue anchors by 10 points down and to the right. There *is* a conflict: the blue width/height is 100 and it seems you are trying to make the brown width/height 80. BUT, that likely means the layout engine is breaking those two because they conflict with the bottom/trailing constraints. (Why do I say that? Because of the result.) BTW, have you checked the console for any conflicts?

Comment: One more item - I just noticed you are making the brown view a subview of the blue one. If you wish to clip the brown view to always stay inside the blue view's bounds, set that flag. Otherwise, you can get the result posted.

Answer (score 1):

> What is going wrong?

I see three classes of problem:

1. Some constraints are not active. The `heightAnchor` and `widthAnchor` constraints have not been set so that `isActive = true`
2. The constraints are in conflict. You are setting constraints based on constants without regard for the dimensions of the superview. This has resulted in constraints coming into conflict, such that, for example, `view1` can’t be 100 points tall *and* 263 points from the top of the superview *and* 284 points from the bottom anchor, all at the same time.
3. Constant-based constraints will usually fail to center a view on the screen because screen sizes vary widely.

Here is one possible solution to these three problems:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    let view1 = UIView()
    view1.backgroundColor = .brown
    view.addSubview(view1)

    view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    view1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    view1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
    view1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
}
```

Here, we have set the X and Y centers of `view1` equal to the X and Y centers of the superview, defined the height and width of `view1` as constants, and set all the relevant constraints to be active.

You can find other solutions in the [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1).

Comment: @Pursuingperfection I believe the 10 point constants you are adding to the top/bottom/leading/trailing constraints are the source of your problem. Replace `view1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.topAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true` with `view1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.topAnchor).isActive = true`, etc., and everything should line up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(true)

let view1 = UIView()
view1.backgroundColor = .brown
view.addSubview(view1)

view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

//Constraints
let centerXConstraint = view1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0)
let centerYConstraint = view1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0)
let widthConstraint = view1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
let heightConstraint = view1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)

//Apply constraints
constraintToApply.append(centerXConstraint)
constraintToApply.append(centerYConstraint)
constraintToApply.append(widthConstraint)
constraintToApply.append(heightConstraint) 
}
```

and also add the below code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    // Apply Constraints
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraintToApply)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Please view my question again I modified it.

Answer (score 0):

You add +10 points to each constraint.

```
view1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.topAnchor, constant:10).isActive = true
```

It means "setup the top anchor of view1 as top anchor of blueView plus 10"

Just remove `constant:10`

```
view1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

And if you setup top, bottom, left, leading and trailing anchors, you shouldn't setup height and width. Width and height will calculate based on these 4 anchors. So, you should remove

```
view1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
view1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
```